# Prestashop mobile template 1.4 module add to cart error

Tags: php, module, prestashop

I have install Prestashop mobile template 1.4 module on prestashop 1.49. It works fine to show mobile responsive template. But on click add to cart button it will redirected to empty cart page.

I have observed that it is an issue due to ajax cart functionality. When I change setting **NO** ajax add to cart it works fine otherwise no item added to cart.

Is there any solution that either I can disable ajax add to cart setting dynamically on mobile or tablet devices in prestashop version 1.49 or solve error of white cart page without adding item into cart.